# How use global media Library in Wordpress multisite

Tags: php, wordpress

I have two WordPress websites, using WordPress Multisite.

For example:

1. `en.example.com`
2. `ua.example.com`

I load my file in `en.example.com` and I want use it in the `ua.example.com` media Library.

I am using this code:

```
function wp_multisite_upload_dir( $dirs ) {
    $dirs['baseurl'] = network_site_url( '/wp-content/uploads' );
    $dirs['basedir'] = ABSPATH . 'wp-content/uploads';
    $dirs['path'] = $dirs['basedir'] . $dirs['subdir'];
    $dirs['url'] = $dirs['baseurl'] . $dirs['subdir'];
    return $dirs;
}
add_filter( 'upload_dir', 'wp_multisite_upload_dir' );
```

But if I load a file in `en.example.com`, I can't see it in `ua.example.com`.

How can I fix this?